# Any easy STEM research articles/papers that high school students can understand?

Tags: publications, reference-request, stem

I'm helping to hold a workshop sort of thing to help students learn how to read/write research papers, but as I am a sophomore and haven't read too many papers myself, I can't find anything that is easily comprehensible for the students. Anything that is not too long and does not have too much jargon will probably work well. I already looked at this paper on mathematically modelling spaghetti curling, which I think is doable, so anything like that, or written simply would be good!

Please help out, I am sort of on a deadline and we need to finalize the papers very soon.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The whole setup of having high school students read research papers seems flawed. See Matt Might's [Illustrated guide to a Ph.D.](http://matt.might.net/articles/phd-school-in-pictures/): You're basically trying to skip two entire levels of required background knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Most recent papers are fairly hard to understand. After all, if they are published, it is because they present something that is not obvious.

You could however use older articles that describe phenomena that have gone on the high school curriculum since. For instance, [here is a paper from 1800](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1800.0015) generally viewed as the discovery of infrared radiation, which somewhat follows today's standard presentation of methods/results/analyses.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with the [answer of UJM](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/150811/75368). Another good paper is the original DNA paper "Molecular structure of nucleic acids" (https://www.nature.com/articles/171737a0.pdf). It's extremely significant and is (in my opinion) very well written.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to SE and appreciate the pointer!